# Android: can't instantiate class : no empty constructor

Tags: java, android, class, constructor, expandablelistview

Please see below, I get a can't instantiate class : no empty constructor error in LogCat when attempting to run my "HomeFragmentListExpand" class even though I clearly have an empty constructor there.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeFragmentListExpand.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    return rootView;

}

public class HomeFragmentListExpand extends Activity {

    public HomeFragmentListExpand(){
        super();
    }


    // more efficient than HashMap for mapping integers to objects
    SparseArray<Group> groups = new SparseArray<Group>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
        createData();
        ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        MyExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,
                groups);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    public void createData() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            Group group = new Group("Test " + j);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                group.children.add("Sub Item" + i);
                }
            groups.append(j, group);
        }
        }
    }

}
```

LogCat.........

```
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{com.smarte.smarteproducts/com.smarte.smarteproducts.HomeFragment$HomeFragmentListExpand}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.smarte.smarteproducts.HomeFragment$HomeFragmentListExpand; no empty constructor
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.smarte.smarteproducts.HomeFragment$HomeFragmentListExpand; no empty constructor
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
01-10 16:41:45.143: E/AndroidRuntime(24809):    ... 11 more
01-10 16:46:46.023: D/Process(24809): killProcess, pid=24809
01-10 16:46:46.023: D/Process(24809): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:123 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

Android Manifest....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.smarte.smarteproducts"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Smartestyle" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.smarte.smarteproducts.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.smarte.smarteproducts.HomeFragment$HomeFragmentListExpand" />
</application>
```

Comment: You call it Fragment but it extends Activity?

Comment: You have a activity class as a inner class of fragment?. post your manifest. I guess you are confused

Comment: Yes, because I cannot put the contents of the activity class in the fragment class.

Comment: @ChrisJamesHancocks there is no reason to create a constructor of activity class. secondly i guess you are confused the way fragmetns and activity work. post your manifest file

Comment: I have added Manifest. I think I am a little confused. Been a while -_-

Comment: @ChrisJamesHancocks move activity out of fragment class. you can pass values from activity to fragment. Also fragment is hosted by a activity.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Instead of starting activity from fragment, why don't you just use activity and call it from wherever you are calling this fragment. Look at the official android documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

FYI activities don't require constructors, whenever they are created, onCreate() method is called.

Comment: Thanks guys, apologies, I was just being a numpty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had been a long day and I was just being stupid. 
Thanks @Raghunandan for pointing this out to me.

I moved the HomeFragmentListExpand into its own class and altered the manifest and all good.

Thanks guys/girls.

Comment: you should also remove the constructor for activity

Comment: I am facing the same problem, although my app was working fine, suddenly it started giving this error, any idea why so